# Add option in event (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a stuck that make me headache so much, as you see picture, this is my result when i add option to event.

[image]

I'm updated code in: `wp-content/theme/mytheme/lib/metabox/function.php`

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'event_date_option',
    'title' => __( 'Event options', 'mytheme' ),
    'pages' => array( Custom_Posts_Type_Event::POST_TYPE ), // Post type
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Event type:', 'mytheme' ),
            'desc' => __( 'Choose event type', 'mytheme' ),
            'id' => SHORTNAME . Widget_Event::EVENT_INTERVAL_META_KEY,
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                array( 'value'=>"n" , 'name' => __( 'Normal', 'mytheme' ) ),
                array( 'value'=>"c" , 'name' => __( 'Comunity', 'mytheme' ) ),
            ),
        ),
```

It's show in event post, but i don't know how to save when add new event OR when i'm update event post. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On publish you will be able to save your meta data through hook [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post), Add ths conde in your functions.php file and just create an array of your all meta field

```
function wpt_save_meta($post) {
    $meta = array(); //array of your meta post i.e $_POST['author_name'] 
    // Add values of $chart_meta as custom field
    foreach ($meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $chart_meta array!
        $value = implode(',', (array) $value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            $id = update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            $id = add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if (!$value)
            delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }
}
 add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_meta'); // save the custom fields
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help for you. Please check.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/